# how to make for loop work properly in vue js

Tags: json, vue.js

i want to assign values in my formdata objects.i have json array. i wanted to asign data in formdata object with for loop but unable to do it..
here is my code below

```
                            let res = response.data;
                        vm.formData = res.data;

                        res.data.go = JSON.parse(res.data.go,true);
                        var len = res.data.go.length
                        var gos = [vm.formData.image1,vm.formData.image2,vm.formData.image3,vm.formData.image4,vm.formData.image5];
                        console.log(res.data.go[0])
                        var i;
                        for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            gos[i] = res.data.go[i]
                            //im++;
                        }
```

Comment: Can you please also share your template and the definition of your component's data?

Comment: can you share some more code to understand it and is there any error in the console ?